# Can someone explain to me the part which is highlighted?

Tags: python

[image]

Im already done with the part before the highlighted part, but i can't understand the part which is highlighted and i dont want to look at the code.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: The whole thingy. how im i supposed to write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

Comment: Your comment already has a number of clauses. You should try each of them before giving up.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
number = int(input("Your number: "))
while number != 1 :
    number = collatz(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, it should be something along the lines:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number // 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    else:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        
def iterate_program:
    number = int(input())
    
    while number != 1:
        number = collatz(number)
```

And then you just call `iterate_program`.

Comment: Have a think about the data type returned by `input`. In its current form, the `while` is an infinite loop.

Comment: @S3DEV correct! Edited my answer.